# Trigger after insert MySQL for order data by date value

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-order-by, insertafter, permanent

> I wanna make tringger, so after inserting data, the datas ordered by date (here name 'tanggal')

> but got error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY tanggal ASC;
> END' at line 5

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sort_by_tanggal
AFTER INSERT ON laporan_bukubesar 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE laporan_bukubesar ORDER BY tanggal ASC;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you can not do that in a trigger

Comment: What storage engine laporan_bukubesar ?

Comment: @P.Salmon MySql sir

Comment: @nbk is there any way to do the same like that? im using 3 tables and combine it into one table, but i need to arrange by date

Comment: not really tables are per definition unsorted, so imposing an order, makes not that much sense, besides ordering the hole table costs tome, and it will be run after **every ** row. which makes even less sens. run your insert and after that make your alter Table, if you still want to